# Using angular attributes with TextBoxFor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using ASP.NET MVC with AngularJs. I am new to AngularJs, I am trying to create a form that uses angularjs.

So to start with I have a login form which asks for username and password.

The username using `Html.TextBoxFor` as shown below

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { ng-model="user.name" })
```

But the ide shows the `ng-model` as an error in red. and gives an error when run with this change.

Error message

> account/login - c:\SVN HOME\ABC-SelfServe\src\ABC\Web\Views\Account\Login.cshtml(23): error CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Till now whenever I had to include html attributes I used to do like this and it used to work. What syntax do I used to include `ng-....` angular attributes with razor `TextBoxFor` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `-` in `new { ng-model="user.name" }` is not valid C#. Change it to `ng_model` and MVC will convert the underscore to a dash on output.

Comment: razor converts every _ to - in the html attributes of Helper?

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you. I realized there no point in using `Html.TextboxFor` or similar razor helper when using angular. I am now using plain html with angular. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. It's a shortcut as underscores are actually not valid in attributes. Can also solve this by using an overload of the helper that takes a Dictionary instead of an object.

Comment: "-", "_" and ":" in attributes are all normalized by angular. They are treated as pascal case "markers". my_attr, my-attr and my:attr are all normalized to myAttr. But angular does not change the html of the attribute.