# Not able to retrieve ng-model value of tinyMCE value

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to retrieve the rich textbox tinyMCE value from the ng-model angular JS. But I'm getting that value as undefined.
The following is the code of my HTML in MVC :

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*<textarea ui-tinymce ng-model="tinymceModel"></textarea>*@
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.QDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "QDescription" } })*@
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.QDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "QDescription" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })            

        </div>

        <div>
            <div text-angular ng-model="htmlContent" name="demo-editor" ta-text-editor-class="border-around" ta-html-editor-class="border-around"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below is the code of my angular controller :

```
angular.controller('PostQuestion', function ($scope, $http) {  
//Insert Question
$scope.saveQuestion = function () {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);
    $scope.PostQuestion = {};
    $scope.PostQuestion.QTitle = $scope.QTitle;
    $scope.PostQuestion.QDescription = $scope.QDescription;        

    alert($scope.QDescription);
    debugger;
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/PostQuestion/InsertQuestion',
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.PostQuestion)
    }).success(function () {
        //GetAllData();
        $scope.empModel = null;
        alert("Employee Added Successfully!!!");
    }).error(function () {
        alert(data.errors);
    });
    GetAllData();
};
```

});

always getting $scope.QDescription is undefined only.

Comment: @Claies , If I give ng-model, I'm getting the error or exception message as like " Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access." yellow screen error.

Comment: @Claies can you suggest how to bring that value then ? Once check this URL too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670868/using-angular-attributes-with-textboxfor-in-asp-net-mvc/